# Optimization problem?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Hi I was having trouble figuring out this question.

Find the point on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in the first quadrant where the tangent line to the circle encloses with the coordinate axes a triangle of the smallest area. Justify your answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the point of tangency be $P=(a,b)$. The tangent line is perpendicular to $OP$, and hence has slope $-\frac{a}{b}$. We find that the tangent line has equation $by+ax=a^2+b^2=1$. The intercepts are at $\frac{1}{a}$ and $\frac{1}{b}$, so we want to minimize $\frac{1}{2ab}$ or equivalently to maximize $2ab$.

From $(a-b)^2\ge 0$ we find that $2ab\le a^2+b^2=1$, with equality if and only if $a=b$. Thus the required point is $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.

Comment: Where did you get (a-b)^2 ?

Comment: Out of the blue, to prove that $2ab\le a^2+b^2$ for all $a$ and $b$, with equality when $a=b$. It is a standard trick.

Comment: Is there any other method to this? Unfortunately I never learned the trick and don't think I'd be expected to use it.

Comment: Sure, the calculus way. We want to maximize $2ab$ given $a^2+b^2=1$. So we want to maximize $2a\sqrt{1-a^2}$ where $0\le a\le 1$. We can now differentiate with respect to $a$ and set the derivative equal to $0$. It is easier to see that maximizing $2a\sqrt{1-a^2}$ is equivalent to maximizing its square $4a^2(1-a^2)$. The derivative is easier to find! I used a non-calculus way because it is more elementary, andalso because I expected people would give a calculus solution that you could accept, and then my version would add to your knowledge. (Cont)

Comment: (Cont) Or else you can use an approach related to two of the answers. Let $a=\cos\theta$. Then $b=\sin\theta$ and we want to maximize $2\cos\theta\sin\theta$. Then differentiate, set the derivative equal to $0$.

Comment: If I was to do it the second way, do you know what reason there'd be to use cosθ and sinθ.

Comment: The parametrization $(x,y)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ of the unit circle is very important. But admittedly differentiating $4a^2-4a^4$ and setting the derivative equal to $0$ is more basic. But then again, $2ab\le a^2+b^2$ is even more basic.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope this helped to solve the problem in your own style.

Answer (score 3):

if we parametrize the circle as $\{P_{\theta}=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)\}_{\theta \in [0,2\pi]}$ then the tangent at $P_{\theta}$ has slope $-\cot \theta$ so its equation is
$$
y-\sin \theta = -\cot \theta (x-\cos \theta)
$$
i.e.
$$
x \cos \theta + y \sin \theta = 1
$$
this intersects the $y$-axis at $(0, \frac1{\sin \theta})$ and the $x$-axis at $(\frac1{\cos \theta},0)$
the area of the triangle is thus $\frac1{\sin 2 \theta}$

for $\theta \in [0, \frac{\pi}2]$ this has a unique minimum at $\theta=\frac{\pi}4$ and the required point is $P_{\frac{\pi}4}=(\frac{\sqrt{2}}2,\frac{\sqrt{2}}2)$

Comment: How did you determine the point to be (cos θ, sin θ)

Comment: @user3495234 Those are the coordinates on a unit circle. It's well known.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to compute this would be to create a function that takes the size as a function of angle $\theta$ as you move the radius around the circle.
Then you note the point of intersection along the circle's circumference, which is $(cos \theta, sin \theta)$. You then need to calculate the slope of the tangent line as a function of angle. The height of the triangle will then be $$sin \theta +m cos \theta$$
The width of the triangle will be $$cos \theta + {sin \theta \over m}$$
You can then use the geometric formula for the area of the triangle, find the critical number, and use that to find the minimum. You can then calculate the point of contact again as $(cos \theta, sin \theta)$. Note that I didn't calculate for you the actual slope of the tangent line, but it should not be difficult to find.